# Problem finding a word in successfully loaded hash table

Tags: c

I've been trying to write a program which loads a dictionary file (which just contains cat and caterpillar) and then spell-checks a .txt file according to the words in the dictionary. I think I have successfully loaded a hash table, but my spell-check function is returning unexpected results.

djb2 hash function from http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~oz/hash.html is used:

```
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    unsigned long hash = 5381;
    int c;

    while ((c = *word++))
    {
        // printf("int c = %i\n", c); // only to visualize function

        hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + tolower(c);
        // printf("hash = %lu\n\n", hash); // only to visualize function
    }

    return hash % N;
}
```

with my load function as follow (I assume my load function is running well since printf is printing expected hash and table[hash(string)] -> word (i.e. Word is cat and hash is 25):

```
// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

const unsigned int N = 100;
#define LENGTH 45;
char string[LENGTH + 1]; // to be used in load() and unload()

...
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    // Step 1: Open dictionary file
    FILE *dictfile = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (dictfile == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Step 2: Read strings from file and create a node one at a time
    while (fscanf(dictfile, "%s", string) != EOF) // file pointer is automatically incremented
    {
        node *n = malloc(sizeof(char)*(LENGTH + 1));
        if (n == NULL)
        {
            return false;
        }

        strcpy(n->word, string); // copies string from source string to n->word
        n->next = NULL;

        // Step 3 and 4: Hash word to obtain hash value and insert node
        if (table[hash(string)] == NULL) // if array in hash table is not pointing to anyth
        {
            table[hash(string)] = n; // link it to node n
            printf("Word is %s and hash is %i\n", table[hash(string)] -> word, hash(string)); // Test if linking is successful
        }
        else // if array in hash is already linked to something
        {
            n->next = table[hash(string)]; // new node points to what table[hash(string)] is pointing
            table[hash(string)] = n;
        }

        free(n);
        dictionary_size++;
    }

    printf("dictionary size is %i\n", dictionary_size);
    return true;

}
```

However, when I want to run an easy .txt file containing the word cat with my spell-check function:

```
// Prototype to check if check function is working
bool check(const char *word)
{
    unsigned int hash_value = hash(word);
    printf("Word is %s and hash is %i\n", table[hash_value] -> word, hash_value);
}
```

It returns Word is [blank] and hash is 25, even though I was expecting it to be "word is cat". I could really use some help in identifying the bug in my code, as I've spent a tremendous amount of time trying to do so (caveat: still learning C). Thank you so much!

Comment: `sizeof(node) != sizeof(char)*(LENGTH + 1)` You allocate to little memory for the node structures.

Comment: Furthermore, `free(n);` will free the node you just created, making all pointers to that node invalid. You don't save copies of the node in the hash-table, but rather copies of the *pointers* to the nodes.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help @Someprogrammerdude. My code is working now and hope you had a great weekend!